# Convert an exported rule to a programmatic rule

Tags: rules

I created a Rule through the GUI and it works fine.  I would like to convert this into a programmatic rule that I can include with my custom module.  This way I dont have to re import my rule every time I set up a site.  Is there any way to do this (other than manually)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_default_rules_configuration()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_default_rules_configuration/7)

> This hook is invoked when rules configurations are loaded. The implementation should be placed into the file MODULENAME.rules_defaults.inc, which gets automatically included when the hook is invoked.

and use [`entity_import()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_import/7) to convert the export string into something Rules will understand. e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_default_rules_configuration() {
  $items['my_rule'] = entity_import('rules_config', 'EXPORT STRING HERE');

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: I'm close to successfully implementing this but on reinstalling the module it's telling me `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'plugin' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {rules_config} (name, status, module) VALUES`...

Comment: You can also use `rules_import('EXPORT STRING HERE')` instead of `entity_import()`.