# How to import rules on site install?

Tags: rules, installation

When I go and export my rule, I get the following:

```
{ "rules_vote_points" : {
    "LABEL" : "Vote points",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "userpoints_rules", "voting_rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "voting_rules_insert_node" ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "3",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "node" ],
          "operation" : "Insert",
          "display" : 1,
          "moderate" : "approved"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Where could I put this to import it in the site install? E.g. I am importing views with a `hook_views_api` hook in my module and a `module.views_default.inc` file that searches through the views folder and imports the views, and content types are created with hook_install in .install files in my modules. But how do I import the following?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80244/convert-an-exported-rule-to-a-programmatic-rule/80255#80255 should help

Comment: Similar case with entity registration: {
  "name" : "participant",
  "label" : "Participant",
  "locked" : "0",
  "weight" : "0",
  "data" : null
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for D7, try this code (which includes a copy of your exported rule):

```
function my_module_default_rules_configuration() {
  $configs = array();
  $rule = '{ "rules_vote_points" : {
      "LABEL" : "Vote points",
      "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
      "REQUIRES" : [ "userpoints_rules", "voting_rules" ],
      "ON" : [ "voting_rules_insert_node" ],
      "DO" : [
        { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
            "user" : [ "node:author" ],
            "points" : "3",
            "tid" : "0",
            "entity" : [ "node" ],
            "operation" : "Insert",
            "display" : 1,
            "moderate" : "approved"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }';
  $configs['rules_vote_points'] = entity_import('rules_config', $rule);
  return $configs;
}
```

PS: have a look at the code of the [Answers Userpoints](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/answers/tree/answers_userpoints) module for an example where this technique is used also (contained in `answers_userpoints.rules_defaults.inc`).